# Views Block displaying above node content

Tags: views, blocks, nodes

I created a block using *Views* which is displayed on some particular content. However the block is being displayed before the main content. I tried changing the row weight for the block but this was no use.

All I need is to display the block after the node content.

Comment: both of them are in same region?

Comment: yes!, they are in same `content` region. and i even tried out with  weights but its not working and

Comment: play with weights, for example give -20 to block and +20 to main content

Comment: Its not working out.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try out the below images step by step, i believe you are the evolving this step before you do with other `blocks` and `pages`

[image]

And see if that

`Show block on specific pages` are in

`All pages except those listed` or

`Only the listed pages`..

[image]

Make that to `All pages except those listed` and check that out..

Comment: wow!, excellent, i got that.. thanks Clive and @Mohammad Ali Akbari

Comment: Weird. Mine was already set to `All pages except those listed` so i changed it to `Only the listed pages` saved it, then set it again to `All pages except those listed`, saved it and it worked. Any explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

I know you've mentioned that you've tried the row-weights on the block page and it hasn't worked, but this is 100% definitely the correct way to order blocks within regions. For example:

[image: Screenshot]

In that example the Search Form comes after the main page content (which is a block in Drupal 7), which includes the node content, for every page on which it's active. I've tried it with blocks made from Views as well and it work exactly as expected.

I guess it's possible that you have some theme preprocessing/template override that might be re-ordering the blocks but I can't imagine why you'd have that and not know about it.

If that's not the case the only thing I can really suggest is check to make sure you don't have any rogue CSS causing that particular block to appear above the node content. It's a long shot but it may be the case.

If you've checked your theme's template.php file and page template files, and the CSS, and it still doesn't work, I can only advise re-installing/overwriting your Drupal core files as it's likely there's something wrong with the one you're currently working with.

Comment: I also have tried this and it's 100% working